# How to convert a set to a list? 'list object is not callable

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a list that contains all the values in the 1st list that aren't in the 2nd list. I looked online and found this solution:

```
list_1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list_2=[2,3]
list_3 = list(set(list_1) - set(list_2))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

If I try this without wrapping in in list(), it does return the correct set, but if I try to convert that set to list I get the same type error. How can I convert this set to a list? Or is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you previously named a variable `list` ? It looks like you've overwritten the built-in `list()` constructor.

Comment: The code works fine for me.

Comment: Apparently this is something wrong specifically with Anaconda Spyder. Tried it in Jupyter notebooks and it works fine. If anyone has any ideas why this wouldn't work specifically in Spyder, please let me know.

Comment: You've been around here for almost two years now, so you should know this; but just a reminder that [you are expected to attempt some research before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Answering a question like this is as simple as copying and pasting `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` into the Stack Overflow search. You should also at least try to read and understand error messages, and make sure that you can reproduce the problem starting from scratch.

Comment: "If anyone has any ideas why this wouldn't work specifically in Spyder" Because of what it says at the linked duplicate. It has nothing to do with Spyder. If you restart Spyder and try only this code starting from scratch, I assure you it will work fine. Unless you have somehow set up some other code to auto-run on startup or something.

Comment: I created a brand new file in Spyder and it still returns this error, not sure how copying and pasting the error into StackOverflow would have resolved this. This seems to be an issue with Spyder.

Comment: Then you have a tech support question with Spyder, not a programming question.